# WORD 2010 crashing when adding ActiveX controls to header section of the document

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word

I am opening a word document from my .net windows application. I am trying add an ActiveX control to the header section of the document. As soon as the control is added, WORD crashes. Any idea why this behavior happens only when the document is opened from a different application ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: sounds painful. Have you heard of Aspose?

Comment: No, I never heard of that. I will google and find out. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Why look? Here it is http://www.aspose.com/word-component-suite.aspx